# OPENQUERY syntax issue SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a function that returns a table that will need to be called remotely. Since this functionality is not supported by SQL at the moment, I will need to utilize `OPENQUERY` to do the following

```
OPENQUERY([Linked_Server],'Query')
```

However, I keep getting a syntax error when I put in the ip address for the linked server. Linked server is setup properly from the looks of it. I am getting the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPENQUERY'.

The script is:

```
OPENQUERY('NN.NNN.N.NN','SELECT * FROM dbo.DBarBillers')
```

(where N's are the digits of the defined linked server's IP address).

Intellisense is putting the red line under `OPENQUERY` and the linked server argument

I have tried unquoting the ip address, and bracing it instead of quoting and all are yielding errors. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You need to select from the `openquery` so the syntax is

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([Linked_Server],'SELECT * FROM dbo.DBarBillers')
```